# jQuery datepicker - change display of .ui-datepicker-calendar after init

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

How can I change the css display attribute of the ui-datepicker-calendar class after the datepicker has already been initialized? I have a html form with a selectable checkbox from which I want to toggle the display of this table. I've tried the following:

HTML sample:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="adddescr"><label for="date">Zeitraum:</label></div>
  <div class="addinput" id="date"><input type="text" id="datefrom" name="datefrom" class="date" /> - <input type="text" id="dateto" name="dateto" class="date" /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="addinput"><label><input type="checkbox" id="dateplanedcheck" /> grobe Planung</label></div>
 </div>
```

JS first approach:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datefrom, #dateto").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",

   [...]

    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
     if ($("#dateplanedcheck").is(':checked')) {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css("display", "none");
    }}
   });

   [...]

  });
 <script>
```

The beforeShow is called, but the calender is still displayed.

JS second approach:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  [....]

   $("#dateplanedcheck").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css("display", "none");
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
```

What am I missing? Does this even work with jQuery?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to NOT show the calendar if the checkbox is checked?

Just `return false;` in the beforeShow.

```
$("#datefrom, #dateto").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        if ($("#dateplanedcheck").prop('checked')) {
            return false;
           }

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JzbPD/

**Answer:**

Still displaying the calendar but making it invisible:

BeforeShow can't access the ui-datepicker-calendar on the table because it hasn't been rendered yet. Apply a class like`$(inst.dpDiv).addClass('calendar-off')` and then have the style `.calendar-off table.ui-datepicker-calendar { display none; }` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JzbPD/4

Comment: well, no. I whant to show the calendar.. I just whant to hide the table with the days when the checkbox is checked. The rest should be displayed (month,year,navigation,...). see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#theming

Comment: Ah ok - from what I can tell, in BeforeShow you can't access the ui-datepicker-calendar on the table because it hasn't been rendered yet. What you could do is apply a class like `$(inst.dpDiv).addClass('calendar-off')` and then have the style `.calendar-off table.ui-datepicker-calendar { display none; }` like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JzbPD/4/

Comment: @Benno...great answer. Especially since it shows how to have multiple different looks on the same page.