# Styling issue with jquery datepicker for IE (Ruby on Rails 3)

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

I am using RoR 3.1 with jQuery 1.7. For most of my pages, I am using the Date Picker library styled to remove the calender object (i.e. the days) :

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
 **display: none;**
}

.ui-datepicker{
margin-left: 138px;
z-index: 1000;
margin-top: -30px;
position: relative;
}
```

This is located in `application.css.scss`. Now, for two of my pages, I need to show the calender object. My solution that works for FF and Chrome is to put the style in the `head` section of the relevant pages:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
**display: block;**
}
</style>
```

This does not work for IE 8 and 9 however, and instead IE picks up the css styling from `application.css.scss`. Any workarounds specific for IE, and better yet, that works across browsers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround using javascript/jquery. See [jQuery datepicker - change display of .ui-datepicker-calendar after init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371690/jquery-datepicker-change-display-of-ui-datepicker-calendar-after-init?rq=1)

Essentially, I force IE to load another class before showing the date-picker.