# Hide ui-datepicker-calendar based on element attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have multiple `inputs` on my page, all of which have jQuery UI's [`datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) widget attached to them.

What I would like to do is `show/hide` the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` based on a `data-calendar` attribute on the `input` element.

For example:

```
<input type="text" data-calendar="false" />
<input type="text" data-calendar="false" />
<input type="text" data-calendar="true" />
```

So, the first two should not show the `.ui-datepicker-calendar`, but the last should.

I thought I could leverage the `beforeShow` event to set the display of the element, however, at the time the event fires, the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` does not yet exist:

```
$('input').datepicker({
  beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').toggle( !$(el).is('[data-calendar="false"]') );
  }
});
```

I've had a look at similar questions, and the answer is to use CSS to hide the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` element:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

However, this won't work for me as I need to set the display property based on the element's `data-calendar` attribute.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I had a look through the [`datepicker` API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but didn't come across anything.

#### [Here's a simple base fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Wm/2/)

#### [Here's how I would like it to display, if `data-calendar` is false](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Wm/3/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having done some more searching, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371690/jquery-datepicker-change-display-of-ui-datepicker-calendar-after-init) which helped me solve my problem.

When the `beforeShow` event fires, add/remove a class on the `#ui-datepicker-div` element (this exists once the datepicker has been attached).

```
$('input').datepicker({
  beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggleClass('hide-calendar', $(el).is('[data-calendar="false"]'));
  }
});
```

Then, just add a style for `.ui-datepicker-calendar` within the `.hide-calendar` class:

```
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

#### [Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Wm/99/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the data attribute for each input element.

1) [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) - Method used to Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements.

2) [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - Method used to iterate objects of jQuery.

Try this.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).data('calendar'));
    if($(this).data('calendar')){
        $(this).datepicker();
    }
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Wm/5/)

From your comments,

```
$('input').datepicker();
$('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('calendar')) {
        $(this).datepicker();
    }
    else{
        $(this).datepicker('destroy');  //Removes the datepicker functionality 
    }
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Wm/6/)

Comment: Thanks, but that only attaches the `datepicker` to elements with `data-calendar="true"`. The requirement is to attach the datepicker to all `inputs`, but only show the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` where the element's `data-calendar` is not false. See the second fiddle for clarification

Comment: @billyonecan Ok. I understood.  check the updated fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that still isn't it. I want the datepicker to show up on all elements, but hide the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` if the element's `data-calendar` attribute is `false`