# Datepicker hide calender to show month-year and full calendar not working properly

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have two fields in my form, one displays a datepicker to show only month and year, and other show full calendar.

```
From <input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker"/>
To <input type="text" name="enddate" id="datepicker1"/>
```

The javascript is :

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, widget) {
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    },
}).click(function(){
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
});

$('#datepicker1').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true, 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
}).click(function(){
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();
});
```

Upto this, the both calendar works fine. But when we change the month or year for the first calendar, the full calendar displays ! I tried adding hide calendar in`onChangeMonthYear` but not working !

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4HxsF/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is a hack, you're trying to hide the calender part  when a month or year is displayed, but the custom `onChangeMonthYear` event fires before the datepicker displays.

To just keep further hacking it, you could use a timeout to defer

```
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, widget) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
        });
    },
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/4HxsF/6/)

Comment: Thanks @adeno for answer with explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide the calendar table with css. This solution will not cause a flickering like the setTimeout solution.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

If you have another DatePicker with a calendar table you want to show, add a click event on it and set his onChangeMonthYear event.

```
$(".class").click(function () {
    // eq = 2 if you already have 2 DatePickers
    $("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").eq(2).prop('style', 'display: block !important');
});

onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(inst.dpDiv).find("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").prop('style', 'display: block !important');
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**: The code above works with Firefox but not with Chrome and IE.
 This code works with Firefox, Chrome and IE:

```
$(".class").click(function () {
    // eq = 2 if you already have 2 DatePickers
    $("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").eq(2).removeClass("ui-datepicker-calendar");
});

onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(inst.dpDiv).find("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").removeClass("ui-datepicker-calendar");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185604/922713) you need to hide it in **beforeShow** instead of onChangeMonthYear. First you need to define a new css Style:

```
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

and in your beforeShow event in datepicker() function:

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
     $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('hide-calendar');
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.