# jquery datepicker one month year only other with day

Tags: jquery

I would like to display two datepickers on a page
one needs to be month and year only
the other needs to have days too.

So I can create month/year only 
with

```
$(function() {        


    $( "#datepickerTEXT" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true,
                    showButtonPanel : true,
                    dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
                    defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', "01/"+$("#datepickerTEXT").val()), 
                    onClose : function(dateText, inst) {
                        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    }
                });


});
```

but when I apply

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display:none;
}
```

this affects my default datepicker too.
Is there a better way.

How should I change the style between each datepicker?

Edit:
I am useing ui-datepicker-calendar because this is the class that styles the jquery calendar box.
For one datepicker instance on my page I want it hidden for the other I want it displayed.

Comment: why are you using `ui-datepicker-calendar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.calendar-off table.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display:none !important;
}

$("#changeDate").datepicker({
       beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
         $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('calendar-off');     
       }
})
```

see Benno's answer @ [jQuery datepicker - change display of .ui-datepicker-calendar after init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371690/jquery-datepicker-change-display-of-ui-datepicker-calendar-after-init)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to target a specific date picker with styling individually, couldn't you just do:

```
#datepickerTEXT {
  display:none;
}
```

?